# How to add built-in function (gettext) to pyright?

Tags: python, gettext, built-in, built-in-types, pyright

I have a python project with gettext. And I use `gettext.install` for adding `_` to built-ins, so it works correctly. But my pyright always shows error: `_ is not defined`. How can I let pyright know this function?

My `pyrightconfig.json`:

```
{
    "venvPath": ".",
    "venv": "env"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the pyright documentation, you can add custom built-in types by adding a `__builtins__.pyi` file to the root of your project.

```py
# __builtins__.pyi
def _(str:str) -> str: ...
```

See [Extending Builtins](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/builtins).